# nginx-proxy path based routing gives 404 error for application assets

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm attempting to use the path based routing feature of `nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy` to host dozzle at http://media.local/dozzle/.

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d"

  dozzle:
    container_name: dozzle
    image: amir20/dozzle:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=media.local
      - VIRTUAL_PATH=/dozzle/
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
```

When I load http://media.local/dozzle/ in chrome, I get a blank page with the dozzle favicon. The chrome dev tools report

```
/dozzle/:15     GET http://media.local/assets/main-aeb02c57.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
/dozzle/:16     GET http://media.local/assets/main-299e3767.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried this with services other than dozzle and the result is the same, so I do not think this is a dozzle-specific issue. How can I get the path based routing to include all of the application assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dozzle creator here. You haven't configured Dozzle correctly. If you want to route all your traffic to a different base, ie. `/dozzle/` then you need to provide `DOZZLE_BASE` env variable. Example [here](https://github.com/amir20/dozzle?tab=readme-ov-file#changing-base-url).

Comment: That works for Dozzle.  Does this mean that any service I put behind the reverse proxy will need to support an alternative base configuration as Dozzle does? Also, Dozzle is awesome, thanks for your hard work.

Comment: I can't speak for every service. But reverse proxies won't rewrite assets. So like `/style.css` won't be rewritten to `/base/style.css` unless the application is smart enough to look at the URL. So generally speaking, you want to make sure the application works with a new base, before doing any kind of proxy.

Comment: And you are welcome. It has been a fun little projet.